Why CGO_FLAGS not point to the include file when go build?
I go get portaudio go module. And try to run the examples.
go build mp3.go

And it reports
# github.com/bobertlo/go-mpg123/mpg123
../../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/bobertlo/go-mpg123@xxx/mpg123/mpg123.go:8:10: fatal error: 'mpg123.h' file not found
#include <mpg123.h>

I already instal portaudio lib using homebrew. So i can find:
include file in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpg123/1.32.3/include.
lib file in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpg123/1.32.3/lib.
What I tried
I try to build with:
CGO_FLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpg123/1.32.3/include" go build mp3.go

but it didn't work, report same error above.
I try to add #cgo CFLAGS: -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpg123/1.32.3/include in /Users/xxx/go/pkg/mod/github.com/bobertlo/go-mpg123@xxx/mpg123/mpg123.go file.
/*

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpg123.h>
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpg123/1.32.3/include  (i added)
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lmpg123

...
*/
import "C"

but it also didn't work. WHY?

I try export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpg123/1.32.3/include. this time, it works. But i still don't get it, why this command works?
